# Reopen SqlDataReader after closing

Tags: c#, sql

I have the following:

```
SqlDataReader reader = new SqlDataReader();
reader.Close();
```

I want to open the reader after I closed it. How can I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. Once something is closed (or disposed) in .NET, there is usually no way to reopen it.